# Old cardboard ceiling tile replacement - where to buy?

Tags: tile, ceiling

Thank you to the people that responded. I didn't realize asking for recommendations were against the rules. When dealing with older homes, it's not necessarily how to repair but how to find replacements.

Recently run into a problem at a friend's home. Some the cardboard 12"*24" ceiling tile is damaged.  I read an article about replacing some damaged tile. I have been searching for awhile to find replacements similar but I cannot find where to purchase or even a manufacturers. [image: see picture of cardboard ceiling tiles]

From post I read - This type of tile is composed of pressed fiber material. They have edges that engage each other in a tongue-and-groove arrangement. They're typically installed on 1x2 battens running under the continuous seams.

Comment: shopping questions are off topic here

Comment: a quick fix would be filling those cracks with plaster

Answer (score 1):

Low Density (wood) Fibreboard ceiling tiles. (eg Pinex(tm))

Assuming  the leak that caused that has been fixed, steam the bent part a bit until it becomes flexible then nail it back up.

They are a fire hazard and may have been discontinued. You might have to go to a house breaker to get replacements.

Answer (score 0):

Try local reclamation businesses. I needed slightly smaller ceiling tiles not so long back and I found a reclamation business that had boxes in the rear of the store.

These are harder to find as the material is outdated, heat inefficient and can prove to be a fire hazard.